# Meaning of parameters in a Google search query?

Tags: search-engine, google-search, query-string

Are there any resources on what the parameters in a Google query mean? Any analysis how the Google search pages work internally?

Examples would be:

- `http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=lol&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&fp=45675624562456`
- `http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=11&ved=KJSGHFKSDJF&url=sfdgagasdgasdgasgasg&rct=j&q=fghthwrteghedgf&ei=asdfasdfsa&usg=asdfasdfasf`

Comment: I've looked all the links pointed in this page plus some more research to no avail to understand what `&gws_rd=cr` do.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be a programming problem; rather it appears to be more of a [Web Application](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) usage question.

Comment: I agree, @M.Justin – and I think it's a bit funny that this happens after 12 years! :D

Comment: This really seems to be a recurring trope. See [1](/q/7446975) [2](/q/8325055) [3](/q/13023196) [4](/q/14271747) [5](/q/18218943) [6](/q/27096026) [7](/q/44192904) [8](/q/48414929) [9](/q/60474392) [10](/q/70866734)
and entrypoints to [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116105/what-are-the-different-parameters-used-in-google-search) and [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/653295/what-is-the-aqs-parameter-in-google-search-query)

Answer (score 7):

- q=searchstring is the search string
- source=something is where the search originated (www.google.com webpage, Google Toolbar, Quick Search of various browsers)
- ie=utf8 input encoding
- oe=utf8 output encoding
- rls=en ?interface language?

Answer (score 1):

&gws_rd=cr is related to redirects too countries. For example if you wanted to get to google.com in UK you need to append that parameter, if not you get redirected to google.co.uk

https://www.branded3.com/blog/country-specific-rank-checking-google-web-server-redirect-gl-gws_rd/