# Is it possible to make a link for Google search results page with a search word?

Tags: hyperlink, google-search

Can I create a link which will open a Google search results page in a new tab with a specific search word?

Consider 10 topics names are displayed, when user clicks on a topic1 (named as photography), a new tab should be opened and that should display Google search results for that topic1 (search results of 'photography').

Is it possible to implement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to populate the 'q' URL parameter, eg

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=photography" target="_blank">Photography</a>
```

Or if you want to specifically return an image search for example, then pass the 'tbm' URL parameter, eg

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=photography&tbm=isch" target="_blank">Photography</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. While searching manually the URL having some other parameters and is in this format: `https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=db4kVpm8Oe_I8AeAlZXQCg&gws_rd=ssl,cr&fg=1#q=photography`. Dont we need to care about other parameters?

Comment: You don't **need** the other parameters - but you might want them depending upon if/how you want to format and/or filter the results. This existing question contains some useful discussion relating to Google search query URL parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401115/meaning-of-parameters-in-a-google-query